# Biblatex APA several works of same author, wrong output

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style, multiple-citations

I have a problem with my citations using biblatex/biber with apa-style. I have some works that share the same first author.The output i get is somewhat weird, even though i have no works from the same year with identical authors, in-text-citations contain the first letter of the authors name.
This looks like: (E. Diener et al., 2018, S. 3), this problem also appears for works with two authors: (E. Diener & Diener, 1995, S. 653).

The output i need would rather look like this: (Diener et al., 2018, S. 3); (Diener & Diener, 1995, S. 653).

I also tried to fix the issue by using `uniquelist=false` or `uniquelist=minyear`, but unfortunately it didn´t help.

Does anybody know a way to fix this, this would really help me.

Find attached a MWE and my .bib entries:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[parsikip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm,top=2.1cm, bottom=19mm,includehead=false,footskip=10mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{color}          


\usepackage[style=apa, datelabel=comp, uniquelist=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{litSM.bib}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc = all, draft = false, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot, nogroupskip, nonumberlist, nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{passiv}{PNSM}{passive Nutzung sozialer Medien}



\setglossarystyle{listdotted}
\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{.6\linewidth}


\clubpenalty=10000                                          % Verhindert einzelne Absatzzeile am Ende oder am Anfang
\widowpenalty=10000                                         % einer Seite.
\displaywidowpenalty=10000                                  %
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\anf}[1]{\glqq{}#1{}\grqq{}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
%   \renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}%
%   \renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}%
}


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=2}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{%
        #1%
        \ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
        or
        ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
    }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
    \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
        \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%%%%% Oxford-Komma vor & %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\addcomma\space\&\space}}

\newcommand{\zittext}[2]{\parencite[S. #2]{#1}}
\newcommand{\hervor}[2]{\parencite[S. #2, Hervorheb. i.O.]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage                      
\printglossary[title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis, type=\acronymtype]

\newacronym{pim}{PIM}{politische Internet-Memes}
\newacronym{mk}{MK}{Meme-Kommunikatoren\_innen}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{Einleitung}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

These are all bib entries of this author:

```
article{dienerdiener95,
    title={Cross-Cultural Correlates of Life Satisfaction and Self-Esteem},
    author={Diener, Ed and Diener, Marissa},
    journal={Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
    volume={68},
    number={4},
    pages={653--663},
    year={1995},
}

@incollection{sciencewb,
    title={Subjective Well-Being},
    author={Diener, Eduard},
    editor={Diener, Eduward},
    booktitle={The Science of Well-Being. The Collected Works of Ed Diener},
    year={2009},
    pages={11--58},
    publisher={Springer},   
    doi={10.1007/978-90-481-2350-6_2}
}

@incollection{happiness,
    title={THE OBJECTIVE BENEFITS OF SUBJECTIVE WELL-BEING},
    author={De Neve, Jan-Emmanuel and Diener, Ed and Tay, Louis and Xuereb, Cody},
    editor={Helliwell, John and Layard, Richard and Sachs, Jeffrey},
    booktitle={WORLD HAPPINESS REPORT 2013},
    pages={54--79},
    year={2013},
    publisher={UN Sustainable Development Solutions Network}
}

@article{diener18,
    title={Advances in subjective well-being research},
    author={Diener, Ed and Oishi, Shigehiro and Tay, Louis},
    journal={Nature Human Behaviour},
    volume={2},
    number={4},
    pages={253--260},
    year={2018},
    doi={10.1038/s41562-018-0307-6}
}
 
@article{dieneradvopen,
    title={Advances and Open Questions in the Science of Subjective Well-Being},
    author={Diener, Ed and Lucas, Richard E and Oishi, Shigehiro},
    journal={Collabra: Psychology},
    volume={4},
    number={1},
    year={2018},
    pages={1--49},
    doi={10.1525/collabra.115}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly (and I'm not sure I do, I have only found second-hand accounts of 7th-ed. APA style), APA wants you to add initials to disambiguate first authors with the same family name. Here you have `Diener, Ed` and `Diener, Eduard`, which for Biber are two different names (even though they probably refer to the same person): So disambiguation makes sense if you look at it from that perspective. In fact as I understand you should even see the complete given name in this case. ...

Comment: ...  I'm not sure what APA style has to say about cases where the same author uses slightly different name formats. You could use `uniquename=false,` to get rid of all name disambiguations, which will help in this case, but may be problematic in other cases where you actually want disambiguation.

Comment: That said, if you think this is not what APA style dictates, report this as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues ideally with reference to the relevant sections from the APA manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when trying to quote `dienerdiener95` with two authors sharing the same last name and also the second entry that has the same last name.

It seems that the database gets confused with the double last name in the first`@article` and repeated in another entry. After that, everything goes downhill.

I found a temporary "cure" by enclosing within `{}` the first letter of the second author of the first entry, thus "modifying" it but without printing anything different. It seems a bug to me. Perhaps with the latest version ...

Original result

[image: original]

After the "cure"

[image: after]

```
\documentclass[parsikip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm,top=2.1cm, bottom=19mm,includehead=false,footskip=10mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{color}     

\usepackage[style=apa, 
datelabel=comp,
% uniquelist=false,
 backend=biber]{biblatex}
 
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname45.bib}    
@article{dienerdiener95,
    title={Cross-Cultural Correlates of Life Satisfaction and Self-Esteem},
    author={Diener, Ed and {D}iener, Marissa}, % added {} <<<<<
    journal={Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
    volume={68},
    number={4},
    pages={653--663},
    year={1995},
}

@incollection{sciencewb,
    title={Subjective Well-Being},
    author={Diener, Eduard},
    editor={Diener, Eduard},
    booktitle={The Science of Well-Being. The Collected Works of Ed Diener},
    year={2009},
    pages={11--58},
    publisher={Springer},   
    doi={10.1007/978-90-481-2350-6_2}
}

@incollection{happiness,
    title={THE OBJECTIVE BENEFITS OF SUBJECTIVE WELL-BEING},
    author={De Neve, Jan-Emmanuel and Diener, Ed and Tay, Louis and Xuereb, Cody},
    editor={Helliwell, John and Layard, Richard and Sachs, Jeffrey},
    booktitle={WORLD HAPPINESS REPORT 2013},
    pages={54--79},
    year={2013},
    publisher={UN Sustainable Development Solutions Network}
}

@article{diener18,
    title={Advances in subjective well-being research},
    author={Diener, Ed and Oishi, Shigehiro and Tay, Louis},
    journal={Nature Human Behaviour},
    volume={2},
    number={4},
    pages={253--260},
    year={2018},
    doi={10.1038/s41562-018-0307-6}
}

@article{dieneradvopen,
    title={Advances and Open Questions in the Science of Subjective Well-Being},
    author={Diener, Ed and Lucas, Richard E and Oishi, Shigehiro},
    journal={Collabra: Psychology},
    volume={4},
    number={1},
    year={2018},
    pages={1--49},
    doi={10.1525/collabra.115}
}
    
 \end{filecontents*}
 
\addbibresource{\jobname45.bib}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc = all, draft = false, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}


\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot, nogroupskip, nonumberlist, nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{passiv}{PNSM}{passive Nutzung sozialer Medien}



\setglossarystyle{listdotted}
\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{.6\linewidth}


\clubpenalty=10000                                          % Verhindert einzelne Absatzzeile am Ende oder am Anfang
\widowpenalty=10000                                         % einer Seite.
\displaywidowpenalty=10000                                  %
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\anf}[1]{\glqq{}#1{}\grqq{}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
%   \renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}%
%   \renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}%
}


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=2}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{%
        #1%
        \ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}}}

\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
        or
        ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
    }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
    \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
        \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%%%%% Oxford-Komma vor & %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{%
%    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
%    {}
%    {\addcomma\space\&\space}}

\newcommand{\zittext}[2]{\parencite[S. #2]{#1}}
\newcommand{\hervor}[2]{\parencite[S. #2, Hervorheb. i.O.]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage                      
\printglossary[title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis, type=\acronymtype]

\newacronym{pim}{PIM}{politische Internet-Memes}
\newacronym{mk}{MK}{Meme-Kommunikatoren\_innen}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Einleitung}


\parencite{dienerdiener95}  

\parencite{sciencewb}

\parencite{happiness}

\parencite{diener18}

\parencite{dieneradvopen}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I put together a  MWE to help to pinpoint the origin of the issue

[image: xcv]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend = biber, style = apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname48.bib}    
@article{mooreii,
    author       = {Moore, Gordon and Moore, Eduard},
    title        = {Cramming more components onto integrated circuits},
    journaltitle = {Electronics},
    year         = 1965,
    volume       = 38,
    number       = 8,
    pages        = {114-117},
}

@book{kullbackii,
    author       = {Moore, Gordon and Kullback, David},
    title        = {Information Theory and Statistics},
    year         = 1959,
    publisher    = {John Wiley \& Sons},
    location     = {New York},
}       
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname48.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\parencite{mooreii}

\parencite{kullbackii}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```